# the application crashes when I go to the next page, when I change the page I go to, everything works

Tags: java, android

Error i'm getting, when I change the page I go to, everything works

```
E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myshop, PID: 2327

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.example.myshop/com.example.myshop.ui.Users.HomeActivity}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'java.lang.String com.example.myshop.Model.Users.getName()' on a null object reference
```

page where im trying to go, with product listing

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        ProductsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products");

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Меню");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Здесь будет переход в корзину", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            }

        };
       // drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView userNameTextView = headerView.findViewById(R.id.user_profile_name);
        CircleImageView profileImageView = headerView.findViewById(R.id.user_profile_image);

        userNameTextView.setText(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.getName());
        Picasso.get().load(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(profileImageView);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_menu);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);//somethere here it's crashing
    }
```

The start page, all imports are good
On the initial page, the login was made without verification, since there was the same error when calling the verification method

Comment: You are crashing on a call to `getName()` on a `Users` field or variable. Your code snippet does not show this call.